# Get The Latest Data By DateTime and Name

Tags: sql

How can I get the latest record? 
I'm using the `MAX(DateTime)` and`GROUP BY` but its not getting the data that I need.

**Here is the sample Data**

```
DateTime                | ID     | Name
2014-09-25 07:36:45.193 | 987302 | Allan 
2014-09-25 07:36:45.310 | 987303 | Allan 
2014-09-25 07:37:31.180 | 987304 | Allan 
2014-09-25 07:38:45.193 | 987305 | Jenny 
2014-09-25 07:39:45.310 | 987306 | Jenny 
2014-09-25 07:40:31.180 | 987307 | Jenny
```

**the result should display**

```
2014-09-25 07:37:31.180 | 987304 | Allan
2014-09-25 07:40:31.180 | 987307 | Jenny
```

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT Max(DateTime)  as DateTime, ID, Name FROM tblTimesheetEntry GROUP BY ID, Name

Comment: Also please edit your question to include what version of SQL you are using by adding the appropriate tag(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the reason you're not getting the expected result is because [Id] is unique and you're including it in your GROUP BY clause. Please give the following a try:

```
SELECT [a].[DateTime], [t].[Id], [a].[Name]
FROM (
    SELECT MAX([DateTime]) AS [DateTime], [Name]
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY [Name]
) AS [a]
JOIN [table] AS [t]
ON [a].[DateTime] = [t].[DateTime]
AND [a].[Name] = [t].[Name]
```

As mentioned below by Eric, if there's a duplicate DateTime/Name you may to explore other options.

Comment: This can break if `DateTime` and `Name` has duplicates

Comment: @Landscape Penguine - What if I want to get not the latest data but the data which are left.

Comment: Since no dbms is specified, double quotes instead of square brackets would be even better!

Comment: If want to get the other data, try replacing all of the "[a]"s in the top line with "[i]"s, then change the equal sign in ON [a].[DateTime] = [t].[DateTime] to a not equal sign, "!=".

Answer (score -1):

SELECT Max(DateTime) as DateTime, ID, Name FROM tblTimesheetEntry GROUP BY Name

I guess this should do as you are looking at grouping by name.

Comment: I don't think ID is valid in the select list since it is not contained in a aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.